# How can I use other record's data in query?

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

`F` lets me use current record's data. How can I use other record's data?

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_cumulative_field = models.IntegerField('my_cumulative_field')
    weight = models.FloatField('weight')

    def baz(self):
        difference = # Here I want to get the difference between current 'my_cumulative_field' 
                     # and the greatest among, in the foo_set, the lesser than the current record's.
        my_value = self.foo_set.annotate(
            my_annotation=difference*F('weight')
        ).aggregate(
            my_aggregation=Sum('my_annotation', output_field=models.FloatField())
        ).get('my_aggregation', 0)
        return my_value
```

I have tried

```py
difference = F('my_cumulative_field') - self.foo_set.filter(
    my_cumulative_field__lt=F('my_cumulative_field')
)order_by('my_cumulative_field').last().my_cumulative_field
```

which does not give desirable result.

Refering to related field like `F('bar').my_cumulative_field` doesn't work.

How can I use other record's data in the current query?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I had to combine many functions and classes including `Subquery` and `OuterRef`, `Coalesce`, and `Max`.

```py
from django.db.models import F, FloatField, Max, Subquery, OuterRef
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


subquery = Subquery(self.foo_set.order_by(
    '-my_cumulative_field'
).filter(
    my_cumulative_field__lte=OuterRef('my_cumulative_field')
).exclude(
    pk=OuterRef('pk')
).annotate(
    greatest_among_the_lesser=Max('proportion', output_field=FloatField())
).values('greatest_among_the_lesser')[:1])

foos = self.foo_set.annotate(
    greatest_among_the_lesser=subquery
).annotate(
    adjusted_value=F('my_cumulative_value')-Coalesce(F('greatest_among_the_lesser'), 0.0)
)
```

Then, I could refer to `F('adjusted_value')` later in `Case`-`When` clause, [unlike using `Window`-`Lag` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76620985/django-4-2-window-lag-function-does-not-assess-lag-properly-only-0s-returned).