# Django 4.2 Window + Lag function does not assess lag properly: only 0's returned

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am trying to calculate lag with `Lag` window function and use field reference so that I can refer to it later in `Case` `When` clause. I am using MySQL 8.0.32.

#### Here's something similar to what I have contrived:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    baz = models.IntegerField()

    def my_method(self):
        foos = self.foo_set.annotate(lag=Window(
            expression=Lag('baz', default=0),
            order_by=F('baz').asc()
        )).annotate(output=F('baz')-F('lag'))
        for i in foos:
            print(i.pk, i.output)   # desired result. But I can't use F('output')

        subquery = Subquery(
            self.foo_set.annotate(
                lag=F('baz') - Window(
                    expression=Lag('baz', default=0),
                    order_by=F('baz').asc(),
                )
            ).filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')).values('lag')
        )
        foos = self.foo_set.annotate(output=subquery)
        reference = F('output')
        for i in foos:
            print(i.baz, i.output)   # not desirable
```

As commented, the problem with the first `foos` is that I can't use field reference with `F`. When I try, it says lag function is not for this context: (`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3593, "You cannot use the window function 'lag' in this context.'"`)

On the other hand, for the second `foos`, `Window` function only returns 0's. With `F('baz')`, I get nothing subtracted from `baz`.

#### Example for Extra Clarification

Let's say that I have four instances of Foo: A, B, C, and D. A is the `bar` of B, C, and D. `baz` for B, C, and D is 2, 3, and 4 respectively. So I would like to have `lag` 0, 2, and 3, and `output` 2, 1, and 1 respectively. Later, I need to refer to `output` using `F('output')` in `Case` `When` clause.

---

#### Question

**What do I make of this behavior? How can I have the function properly return desired lag?**

Thank you in advance.